# extracting and substituting string between characters

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, replace

I have cleaned my data which was encoded in `'utf-8'`. Using `.str.extract()`, I got the text enclosed between `[(u'text')]` to `'text` format however, my code is not registering garbage/unicode characters `"\u09xx"` *and similar* type of literals. How should I remove them ?

## Input :

```
{"HT" : ["([u'SoccerTips', u'FootballTips'],)", "([u'\u092b\u094c\u091c\u0940', u'FixedMatch', u'CT2017Final'],)"]}
```

## My code :

```
df1 = df.drop('HT', axis=1).join(
             df.HT
             .str
             .split(expand=True)
             .stack()
             .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
             .rename('HT')           
             )

df1['HT'] = df1['HT'].str.extract("u+(\'[^\']*)", expand=False).fillna('')
df1['HT'] = "#" + df1['HT']
```

## Output :-

```
{"HT" : ["#'SoccerTips" , "#'FootballTips", "#'\u092b\u094c\u091c\u0940", "#'FixedMatch", "#'CT2017Final"]}
```

## Expected Output :-

```
{"HT" : ["#SoccerTips" , "#FootballTips", " ", "#FixedMatch", "#CT2017Final"]}
```

Comment: do you just want to keep ascii characters?

Comment: Yes, If there is a possible way to convert those unicode to ascii then it is a different problem altogether. For now I just want to drop the whole unicode \u literal and substitute it with a blank.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd

# the input
df1= {"HT" : ["([u'SoccerTips', u'FootballTips'],)", "([u'\u092b\u094c\u091c\u0940', u'FixedMatch', u'CT2017Final'],)"]}

# convert to Dataframe
df1= pd.DataFrame(df1)

# cleaning
df1.HT.replace('\(\[|\],\)','', regex=True, inplace=True)
df1.HT.replace("u'[^\x00-\x7f]*'","", regex=True, inplace=True)
df1.HT.replace("u'([^\']+)'",'#\\1', regex=True, inplace= True)
df1.HT= df1.HT.str.split(', ')

# final result
df1= {'HT':[j for i in df1.HT for j in i]}

# output: df1 -> {'HT': ['#SoccerTips', '#FootballTips', '', '#FixedMatch', '#CT2017Final']}
```